# Understanding mvc way of component coding for both joomla 2.5 and 3 version

Tags: component, joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-api

I made a component in joomla 2.5 in mvc way which was not working in joomla 3, later found out it's because in joomla 3 previous mvc classes not working so is controller, view, model classes must be extended from Legacy classes like

> JControllerLegacy, JViewLegacy ,JModelLegacy

and no other changes needed to make component compatible with joomla 3 as far as i knew.If there anything more to know then let me know for compatibility with j3. So instead of making two separate mvc components for joomla 2.5 and 3, i guess i can extend from these Legacy classes so that single component is enough for both joomla 2.5 and 3, right? and again what other things to be considered to produce successful MVC component which can be installed in both joomla versions.

Comment: To run an extension on both platforms, I've found **FoF library** to be the simplest solution https://github.com/akeeba/fof

Comment: I think a good resource for you would be 'Learning Joomla! 3 Extension Development,' by Tim Plummer as much of the book covers step-by-step 'How to upgrade a Joomla! 2.5 component to Joomla! 3.' See https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/learning-joomla-3-extension-development-third-edition

Answer (score 8):

There is a good doc page explaining the differences between Joomla 2.5 and 3.x.

http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2

The only thing to mention is that the legacy classes are only available in Joomla 2.5.5 and higher. But anyone should be on 2.5.19 nowadays anyway :)

Comment: How long does the legacy classes stay for joomla 3 versions?

Comment: They can be removed at earliest with Joomla 4.0.
Currently they aren't even deprecated yet. Feel free to use them.